# How to create a Chord Sample in Logic Pro X

Tags: chords, acoustic-guitar, logic-pro

I start by saying that I'm totally new to Logic Pro.

**I need to sample some guitar chords**

Just that, without strumming or anything, just play the Chord once. 
Is there a way I can do it using Logic without having to record it from my guitar?

I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a free external plugin called 'spicy guitar'.This should simulate an acoustic guitar sound just fine. But if you want something really pro, you want to use 'real guitar' vst by musiclab which costs $199. 'DSK electric guitar z' is a good free one for electric guitar or you can buy the ultimate NI 'guitar rig' for $180